# modify interspace when using in line includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I want to add an image in a text with the following code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\lavanda{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=1.5cm,angle=-60]{lavande_col}}}}

\begin{document}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA \qquad \qquad \qquad$\lavanda$\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

I would like to force the text to follow the contour of the image. So that I would have: (i) the same interspace before and after the image; and (ii) the text not stopping at the border of the image but at the border of the drawing.

And yeah... Unfortunately I do not know how to do that. Can someone help, please?

Comment: You can probably be helped by `shapepar`, https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar. One thing though, TeX does not know (or care) about the contents of the image, so you can not automatically stop at the border of the drawing.

Comment: @StefanH thanks! yeah.. I was hoping in some tikz-trick

Comment: You should take a look at the `insbox` plainTeX macro package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy with the `insbox` plain macro-package: it defines an `\InsertBoxR` command, to be used before a paragraph. It takes two mandatory arguments: the number of untouched lines before the insertion, and the inserted object, and one optional argument: the number of supplementary shorter lines, in case TeX doesn't make a correct computation of the necessary line.
There's like wise an `InsertBoxL` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\input{insbox}
\makeatletter
\@InsertBoxMargin=1.5ex
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{3}{\includegraphics{lavender-drawing}}[1]

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Correct, even down to the lavender!

Comment: Smells better than Pepe-le-Pew!